# Configure hadoop-client to connect to hadoop in other machine/server

Tags: hadoop, hive

On server A i have hadoop and python scripts for performing tasks on hadoop.
On server B i have hive/hadoop. 
Is it possible to configure hadoop-client on server A to be connected to hadoop on server B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what Python library you are using, but assuming PySpark, you can copy or configure the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` on your client machine, and it can communicate with any external Hadoop system.

At the very least, you'll need to configure a core-site.xml to communicate with HDFS and a hive-site.xml to communicate with Hive.

If you are using [PyHive library](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive), you just connect to `user@hiveserver2:1000`

Comment: could you provide an example how to configure hive-site.xml so, that hive would connect to hive in other server? what parameters tels hive to communicate with other hive ?

Comment: Hive doesn't communicate "between Hive servers". Your JDBC/Thrift clients connect directly to the other server. For example with JDBC, you would do `jdbc:hive2://other-hiveserver2:10000`, and that works with beeline

Comment: So my hive-site.xml on server A would have only one property with this driver? What is the property name ?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but if the port for HiveServer2 is open, (`hive.server2.thrift.port`) then Python, or any other client just connects to that port. You don't need any XML files in this case.